# How to set Multiple Option of Payment In PayUMoney Payment Gateway in Android

Tags: java, android, kotlin, payumoney

[image: Image of Output]

my dependency file here

```
implementation 'com.payumoney.sdkui:plug-n-play:1.6.1'
```

payUmoney code

```
 private fun startPay() {
    builder.setAmount(amount)                          // Payment amount
            .setTxnId(txnid)                     // Transaction ID
            .setPhone(phone)                   // User Phone number
            .setProductName(prodname)                   // Product Name or description
            .setFirstName(firstname)                              // User First name
            .setEmail(email)              // User Email ID
            .setsUrl("https://www.payumoney.com/mobileapp/payumoney/success.php")     // Success URL (surl)
            .setfUrl("https://www.payumoney.com/mobileapp/payumoney/failure.php")     //Failure URL (furl)
            .setUdf1("")
            .setUdf2("")
            .setUdf3("")
            .setUdf4("")
            .setUdf5("")
            .setUdf6("")
            .setUdf7("")
            .setUdf8("")
            .setUdf9("")
            .setUdf10("")
            .setIsDebug(true)                              // Integration environment - true (Debug)/ false(Production)
            .setKey(pro_merchantkey)                        // Merchant key
            .setMerchantId(pro_merchantId);
    try {
        paymentParam = builder.build()
        getHashkey()
    } catch (e: Exception) {
        Log.d("afkafbakabkab", " errors $e")
    }

}
```

payment flow stating from here

```
 private fun getHashkey() {
    paymentParam!!.setMerchantHash(CreateHash())
    PayUmoneyFlowManager.startPayUMoneyFlow(paymentParam, this as PaymentGateways, R.style.AppTheme_default, true);

}
```

generating hash key from this code

```
 private fun CreateHash(): String {

    var hashSequence: String = pro_merchantkey + "|" + txnid + "|" + amount + "|" + prodname + "|" + firstname + "|" + email + "|" +
            udf1 + "|" + udf2 + "|" + udf3 + "|" + udf4 + "|" + udf5 +"||||||"+ pro_salt;

    val hash = hashcal("SHA-512", hashSequence)

    return hash

}
```

note :- i am getting only one payment option i want to get multiple payment options like netbanking ,Upi

Answer (score 0):

you have set `setIsDebug()` true; for some resaons PayU have only provided test cards for testing purposes.
So, the release build will have all the options.
in simple words set `setIsDebug(false)` and you will get all the options.